# Forest by particle system and Tree addon?

Tags: particles, parent

I try to make a forest.
I built some tree by the Sapling addon, but every each tree are 2 separated objects: the bole, which is a curve, and the leaves, they are planes. The leaves automatically are parented to the boles. I made group from these tree-boles.

In an other layer, I made a plane, subdivided. etc. and in the Particle system tab-Render-Group section i chose this group as source.
But only the boles are disappeared in the " forest". Why can I not see the "children" leaves?

Comment: If you grouped the tree with leaves, you choose *Group* option (as you did, in Render scroll), select this group and check *Whole Group* option so to use all the elements from group at once, shown exactly as in group.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

I am doing that too and I fix it easily by checking the whole group option